# How to calculate SHAP values after transfer learning Resnet18 model?

Tags: pytorch, transfer-learning, resnet, image-classification, shap

I modified Resnet18 model so it would predict 2 classes (cats and dogs) instead of 1000. I then used SHAP library for plotting the marginal contributions of the features.

On pretrained Resnet18 receiving shap_values works absolutely fine. However, on my modified model I get this error:

*code line*: `shap_values, indexes = e.shap_values(normalize(to_explain))`
RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors does not require grad

The modified model itself works as it should and classifies cats&dogs accurately. The problem emerges only wile using SHAP.

I used only cats-dogs dataset for training. However, in calculating shap values I used the shap.datasets.imagenet50() for simplicity of comparing two models, because it seems like the problem is in the model structure, not the data.

Here's a code for bulding a model:

```
import glob
import warnings

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torchvision.transforms import Compose, Normalize, Resize, ToTensor

device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

!wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/E/1/3E1C3F21-ECDB-4869-8368-6DEBA77B919F/kagglecatsanddogs_5340.zip
!unzip -qq kagglecatsanddogs_5340.zip
!rm -rf PetImages/Cat/666.jpg PetImages/Dog/11702.jpg readme\[1\].txt CDLA-Permissive-2.0.pdf

dataset = ImageFolder(
    "./PetImages",
    transform=Compose(
        [
            Resize((224, 224)),
            ToTensor(),
            Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (1, 1, 1)),
        ]
    ),
)
train_set, val_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(
    dataset, [int(0.8 * len(dataset)), len(dataset) - int(0.8 * len(dataset))]
)

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=256, shuffle=True)
val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_set, batch_size=256, shuffle=False)

import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy
from torchvision.models import resnet18
from torchmetrics.functional.classification import multiclass_accurac

model = resnet18(pretrained=True)

class CatsVSDogsResnet(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, pretrained: bool = False) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.pretrained = pretrained

        if pretrained:
            # <YOUR CODE HERE>
            self.model = resnet18(pretrained=True)
            self.model.fc = nn.Identity()
            self.classifier = nn.Linear(512, 2)
            self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.classifier.parameters())
        else:
            # <YOUR CODE HERE>
            self.model = resnet18(pretrained=False)
            self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters())

        self.loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def forward(self, x) -> torch.Tensor:
        if self.pretrained:
            # <YOUR CODE HERE>
            with torch.no_grad():
                features = self.model(x)
            preds = self.classifier(features)
        else:
            # <YOUR CODE HERE>
            preds = self.model(x)
        return preds

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return self.optimizer

    def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx) -> torch.Tensor:
        images, target = train_batch
        preds = self.forward(images)
        loss = self.loss(preds, target)
        self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, val_batch, batch_idx) -> None:
        images, target = val_batch
        preds = self.forward(images)
        loss = self.loss(preds, target)
        acc =  multiclass_accuracy(torch.argmax(preds, dim=-1).long(), target.long(), num_classes=2)
        self.log("val_loss", loss, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("accuracy", acc, prog_bar=True)

cats_vs_dogs_pretrained = CatsVSDogsResnet(pretrained=True)

trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator="gpu", max_epochs=1)
trainer.fit(cats_vs_dogs_pretrained, train_dataloader, val_dataloader)
```

And the part with SHAP:

```
import json
import shap

mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

def normalize(image):
    if image.max() > 1:
        image /= 255
    image = (image - mean) / std
    # in addition, roll axes so that they suit pytorch
    return torch.tensor(image.swapaxes(-1, 1).swapaxes(2, 3)).float()

#model = resnet18(pretrained=True).eval()
model = cats_vs_dogs_pretrained.eval()

X, y = shap.datasets.imagenet50()
X /= 255

to_explain = X[[1, 41]]

# load the ImageNet class names
url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/deep-learning-models/image-models/imagenet_class_index.json"
fname = shap.datasets.cache(url)

with open(fname) as f:
    class_names = json.load(f)


e = shap.GradientExplainer((model, model.model.layer1[0].conv2), normalize(X))
# while using resnet18 change to model.layer1[0].conv2

shap_values, indexes = e.shap_values(normalize(to_explain), ranked_outputs=2, nsamples=2)

#↑↑↑ Here the error emerges.
```